# Capturing data stream of a JS / Leaflet animation as MP4

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, leaflet, mp4

How can I capture the datastream of a JS / Leaflet animation and download it to MP4?

I am looking for output that looks something like the smooth path traced in these demos:
https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim

Their author appears to have done them in `ffcast` or some screencasting softare.

However, I am looking for an automated solution that can be run as script, ideally one that works on the data stream itself (not the screen), perhaps with a headless browser.

I have tried [puppeteer-gif](https://github.com/aimerib/puppeteer-gif-cast) and [puppeteer-gif-cast](https://github.com/aimerib/puppeteer-gif-cast) but the best frame rate is jumpy.

I have tried [WebRTC-Experiment](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/ffmpeg) but it requires me to set manual permissions. Ditto the Screen Capture API mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728264/how-can-i-write-a-frame-of-an-embedded-youtube-video-via-iframe-to-a-canvas), though this at least seems to work on the data stream itself.

Comment: Just for the record, I think I used [byzanz/peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) for the snakeanim gif (rather than `ffcast`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [headless chrome capture screen video or animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050259/headless-chrome-capture-screen-video-or-animation)

Answer (score 0):

The canvas [captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method combined with the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) should do the trick.

Mind you that Chrome only supports webm as a container format (but does record h264) so you might need a postprocessing step with ffmpeg.